# Draw arrow not to node center but to edge of circle on this node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, nodes, circles

This example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);

    \node [draw, circle] at (0,0) {};
    \node [draw, circle] at (1,1) {};

    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

plots two circles. But the arrow starts **in** the one circle and ends **in** the other circle. What I need is: starting and ending **on the radius** of the two circles.

How is this possible? Best if it is done automatically/dynmically depending on the size of the circles.

Comment: In this example,  you're not actually using PGFPlots, but only TikZ/PGF. PGFPlots is a plotting environment that uses TikZ/PGF (and loads it automatically). I've edited the tags accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. :) I always don't really know the difference between these two and which command comes from what package actually in the end. ;)

Comment: But what about drawing dotted lines, i.e. \draw[dotted] (c1) -- (c2) because then there is no automatism.
Any idea?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use named nodes. They do that automatically.

To name nodes, use either

- the `name=<name>` key, or
- the special syntax `(<name>)` (see example below)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (1,1);
    \node [draw, circle]          (c1) at (0,0) {};% special syntax
    \node [draw, circle, name=c2]      at (1,1) {};% name key
    \draw[->] (c1) -- (c2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]